# Cómo limitar intentos en Python al ingresar palabras y no enteros en Factorial

Tags: python, python-3.x, bucles, while

Estaba realizando el siguiente ejercicio que consiste en calcular el factorial de un numero ingresado por un usuario y mi pregunta es quiero ponerle 3 intentos si ingresa letras o no numero que se cierre el programa. Les muestro el código que estoy haciendo .

```
while True:
    try:
        resultado=1
        numero=int(input("ingresa un numero: "))
        for i in range (numero,0,-1):
                resultado=resultado*i
        print(resultado)
        break
    except ValueError:
           print ("La entrada es incorrecta: escribe un numero entero")
```

Comment: En vez de `while True` puedes por ejemplo crear una variable previamente que sea un contador, que cuente los intentos, y establecer en el `while` la condición para no más de tres intentos.

Answer (score 1):

La variable `resultado` contiene el factorial calculado. Al comenzar el código, está en `None` para reflejar que nada ha sido calculado aún.

La variable `intentos` cuenta la cantidad de entradas ingresadas por el usuario.

Para controlar que el ingreso se realice un máximo de tres veces o hasta obtener un resultado, usamos un `while`:

```
resultado = None
intentos = 3
while intentos and not resultado:
    intentos -= 1
```

En cada iteración también le restamos uno al número de intentos.

Si la petición de número tiene éxito, la ejecución prosigue con el calculo del factorial:

```
   resultado = 1
   for i in range(numero, 1, -1):
       resultado = resultado * i
```

Al termina, `resultado` contiene el factorial y la condición del `while` ya no se cumple.

**Código completo**

```
resultado = None
intentos = 3
while intentos and not resultado:
    intentos -= 1
    try:
        numero = int(input("ingresa un numero: "))
        resultado = 1
        for i in range(numero, 1, -1):
            resultado = resultado * i
    except ValueError:
        print("La entrada es incorrecta: escribe un numero entero")

if (resultado):
    print(resultado)
```